# Is it possible to achieve such kind of grid layout with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve layout similar to this

[image]

The problem is that I need to use only one **UL** for the boxes and make it horizontal. So here is what I've done:
I created **UL** , and the list items inside it are floating left to each other, but instead of achieving this - here is what happens :

[image]

I can't understand why the second row of list items are becoming positioned that way instead of nesting into the first row?

Comment: use jquery masonry to achieve this

Comment: It'll be much easier for others to help you if you post your code, e.g. on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Usually I see this kind of layout achieved with Javascript and generated absolute positioned boxes. The second image is exactly the behavior you get by using `float: left;`. Imagine the boxes being floated in from one side, since the first row is *full*, the other boxes use the the second one. The empty space belongs to the first row.

Comment: you need http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @Joey I didn't posted my code, because it's trivial. UL + li which is floated left. 

Mr.Kleinfreund if I understand you right - there is no way to do that with pure CSS + HTML solution ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that. I don't know whether flexbox may help you there. But you won't achieve this with floating or `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the **[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Y85/)**

You can Do it by column-count and column-gap

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300/" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x500/" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x500/" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 0px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 0px;
    width: 660px;
    margin: 10px;
}
li {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: It's almost working. I try to prevent the strange cutting of last elements in the columns. My last element of column 1 is cutted and it's firs half is inside column one and the second one is in column two.

Comment: Try adding display:inline-block to li.